# StreamingTextResponse doesn't working correctly in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, langchain

Code which I shared - is api route in Next.js
In dev mode, all working as I expected, but in production, the response seems like static response, so data is sending not dynamically, just like one part

I'm not sure why that happens

On the client side it handled by TextDecoder class, I get chunks with text from api route and add them to state

So as I said, in the dev mode all working like readable stream response, but in production not

used libraries `langchain` and `ai`

```js
import { ChatOpenAI, ChatOpenAICallOptions } from "langchain/chat_models/openai"
import { PromptTemplate } from "langchain/prompts"
import { BytesOutputParser } from "langchain/schema/output_parser"
import { StreamingTextResponse } from "ai"
import { cookies } from "next/headers"
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export async function POST(req: NextRequest): Promise<StreamingTextResponse> {

    if (!cookies().has(/*property_name*/)) {
        return NextResponse.json(null, { status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized" })
    }
    // Request body
    const body: AssistantPayload = await req.json()
    // Messages variable
    let messages: Message[] = body.messages
    // Initialize chat model instance
    const model: ChatOpenAI<ChatOpenAICallOptions> = new ChatOpenAI({
    // ... config properties
    })
    // Parser instance
    const outputParser = new BytesOutputParser()

    const prompt = PromptTemplate
        .fromTemplate(/* I can't share it. It's just system prompt */)

    const history = JSON.stringify( // Create history JSON
        messages.map(m => /* creating required history structure as string */)
    const content = body.prompt // New user message
    const chain = prompt.pipe(model).pipe(outputParser)

    const stream = await chain.stream({ history, content }) // Create readable stream

    return new StreamingTextResponse(stream) // Readable stream response
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by: _"the response seems like static response, so data is sending not dynamically"_?  What actually happens?

Comment: I meant that response sending not like text chunks, but just like one full completed text
But it should sending text as readable stream, like in real time

Comment: Did you fix your issue. If you did can you tell me how did you fix it.

Comment: Oh, unfortunately, I didn't solved it ((

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the streaming works for production builds adding:

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
```

at the beginning of API route that is implementing the streaming.

Source:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48427#discussioncomment-5624604

Comment: Currently this feature is disabled on the project, but I guess this possible way to fix that, thanks, I will check